# ipywidgets & How to evaluate answers on form

Tags: python, events, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I would like to add a form into a jupyter notebook. 
To do this, my idea is:

- Add a RaddioButtons widget
- Add a "Submit answer" button
- Add a function to evaluate the answer

My actual code is:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

selection = widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=['The color', 'The length', 'The slope'],
    value='The slope',
    description='',
    disabled=False
)

button = widgets.Button(
    description='Submit answer',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
)

def evalute(selection):

    if (selection == "The slope"):
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Try again...")
# To reset the option value. However, I would like to avoid having a "default" value
        seleccion = "The color"       

boton.on_click(evaluate(selection.value))        

left_box = widgets.VBox([selection, button])
widgets.HBox([left_box])
```

However, this doesn't work properly. By two things:

- I don't want a default value
- I don't want the method "evaluate" to be executed at the beggining. It should be "on_change"

Could you please help me with this and to "clarify" my missconception?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the very clear code example.

1) You can specify `value = None` for your RadioButtons

2) When setting `on_click` for your Button, just give the function name, don't actually call the function. You are passing the function as an object to the button, to be called when it is clicked (it took me a while to get my head round this).

The button will pass itself to the `evaluate` function, but the widget we really care about is the `selector`.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

selector = widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=['The color', 'The length', 'The slope'],
    value=None,
    description='',
    disabled=False
)

button = widgets.Button(
    description='Submit answer',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
)

def evaluate(button):

    selection = selector.get_interact_value()

    if (selection == "The slope"):
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Try again...")
# To reset the option value. However, I would like to avoid having a "default" value
        selector.value = None     

button.on_click(evaluate)        

left_box = widgets.VBox([selector, button])
widgets.HBox([left_box])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for youe quick answer @ac24! The first point is fixed with your modification. However, the button widget still doesent work properly as when I click into it, the "evaluate" function doesn't print the expected result ("Correct" or "Try again..."). I also tryed to replace: selection = selector.get_interact_value() by selection = selector.value unsuccessfully.  Any idea?

Comment: It works for me on ipywidgets version 7.5.1. Which version are you using? (`widgets.__version__`?)

Comment: The same as yours :S. 7.5.1

Comment: Can you update your original question with screenshot and any errors?

Comment: Sorry, but there are no errors being displayed :(. On clicking the button, correctly resets de value of the RadioButton but it doesn't print the evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. The idea is to make use of the: "interactive_output" function and to remove the Button. It's not excatly how I wanted it but it works for me.

```
def evaluate(a):
    if (a != None):
        if (a == "The slope"):
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Try again...")
    else:
        print("Waiting for an answer")


selector = widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=['The color', 'The length', 'The slope'],
    value=None,
    description='',
    disabled=False
)

#boton = widgets.Button(
#    description='Evaluar',
#    disabled=False,
#    button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
#)

ui = widgets.VBox([selector])
out = widgets.interactive_output(evaluar, {'a': selector})

display(ui, out)
```

[image: Output from the code]